# Get rows from mysql based on last unchanged column data

Tags: php, mysql

I need an SQL query to get only the last rows based on an unchanged column value. How can I do that?

Table : table1

```
ID  LEVEL
1   1
2   1
3   2
4   4
5   3
6   3
7   4
8   5
9   3
10  3
```

I need an SQL query that can give me the last rows containing level 3 till it was unchanged.

e.g

```
select * from table where level = 3 order by ID desc;
```

gives

```
10  3
9   3
6   3
5   3
```

I just want

```
9   3
10  3
```

Comment: Well, the query has returned what you requested, you'll have to narrow it down further by passing some more fields or throwing some more conditions into the mix. You can't say 'I want this data only.' unless you narrow it down. Do you have any other columns?

Comment: In the last two rows level is 3, in the third last row level is 5, i need all the rows from the last where the level is 3, any row above third last row where level is 5, I don't want. I don't want all rows of level 3.

Comment: What if 8 was also level 3?

Comment: Then I want ID 8 also.

Comment: So you don't want to go below ID 8?

Comment: Yes basically as long as level is same, i want all rows, once the level has changed, I dont want any row above it then.

Comment: How you defined "unchanged column data"- from initialization of the table?

Comment: What I meant by changed column data is get all rows till a particular value of a column is unchanged, in this case is the level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

E.g.:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table
(ID SERIAL PRIMARY KEY
,LEVEL INT NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO my_table VALUES
( 1,1),
( 2,1),
( 3,2),
( 4,4),
( 5,3),
( 6,3),
( 7,4),
( 8,5),
( 9,3),
(10,3);

SELECT MIN(id) range_start
     , MAX(id) range_end
     , level 
  FROM 
     ( SELECT x.*
            , CASE WHEN @prev=level THEN @i:=@i ELSE @i:=@i+1 END i
            , @prev:= level 
         FROM my_table x
            ,( SELECT @prev:=null,@i:=0 ) vars 
        ORDER 
            BY id
     ) a 
 WHERE level = 3 -- optional
 GROUP 
    BY level
     , i
 ORDER
    BY range_start DESC 
 LIMIT 1;

  +-------------+-----------+-------+
  | range_start | range_end | level |
  +-------------+-----------+-------+
  |           9 |        10 |     3 |
  +-------------+-----------+-------+
```